# Check/Monitor Amount of SQL Queries per Hour

Tags: cpanel, monitoring, sql, cpu

My website is hosted on a shared hosting and I'd like to know how much SQL queries it is using per hour. I tried to navigate through cPanel and I find nothing to check or monitor the amount of SQL queries per hour. I tried to ask my host and they said it is not possible to do manually.

However I found this http://forum.powweb.com/archive/index.php/t-49937.html and another one on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842094/sql-how-can-i-get-the-number-of-executed-queries-per-database-or-hour-or And since this exists, I assume that it is actually possible. Problem is I can't execute that in my phpmyAdmin.

Can someone here guide me through the process?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really far from an expert on anything SQL / database related, but I think [New Relics](http://newrelic.com/) analytics may have something that can monitor this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do via mySql configuration, but in a shared hosting environment, you should not be able to discover that information unless the server admin made a very big mistake.